# How to handle 'The controller for path '/index' was not found or does not implement IController' in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I am working on Asp.net mvc3 application.For exception handling i using following code in global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception exception = Server.GetLastError();
        Response.Clear();
        HttpException httpException = exception as HttpException;
        Server.ClearError();
        Response.Redirect("/Secure/Error", false);
    }
```

if any exception occur it will redirect to Error page.I want to some exeception should not redirect to Error page.

Like if any user enter following url

> www.example.com/index

there is no controller of '**index**' name it will be throw exception

> The controller for path '/index' was not found or does not implement
>   IController

I want this when this exeception occur it should redirect to **www.example.com**

How can i do this?

There are some other keyword like **index..** that should be redirect to main url of website

Comment: Your controller probably shouldn't be called Index, as that's too general and could lead to issues. It's also worth saying that I've encountered a gotcha a couple of times with RedirectToAction as the signature is - RedirectToAction( "ActionName", "ControllerName".... ), and you might expect the ControllerName and ActionName in the signature to be the other way round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that only for specific keywords, why not add corresponding routes instead of handling the *404 - Not Found* exceptions?

You could do this in your *Globals.asax.cs* file, next to the other route definitions:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "IndexRoute", // Route name
    "index", // URL 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "RedirectToRoot" }
    );
```

and likewise for all keywords other than **index**.

#### Update

After making */index* and the other urls point to `HomeController.RedirectToRoot()` (or another controller/action of your choice), just implement it to return a RedirectResult that would take the user to the site's root:

```
public RedirectResult RedirectToRoot()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

#### Update 2

If you are absolutely sure that you'll never use */index* or the other special urls for anything but redirecting to root, then you could do a permanent redirect instead:

```
return RedirectToActionPermanent("Index", "Home");
```

This will save some round trips to the server, but the redirection will be permanently stored in client browsers, making it very hard/impossible to use those urls for anything else in the future.

Comment: Right. Please see the update to my answer. Basically the special keywords could point to an action that redirects to root.

Comment: @w0lf.Useful answer but if i have ten keywords.how can i handle?any other suggestion

Comment: you could call `routes.MapRoute(...)` in a `foreach` loop that iterates through your 10 keywords.